# Countdown indicator to end of beta (or count up from the start)

Tags: support, beta

I don't see an easy way to find out how long this site has been in beta for - this sounds like a fairly easy, useful, feature to add to the stack-exchange sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stats for the beta period can be found at the [Area51 page for RPG](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games).

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is the launch pad for new Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It's difficult to ascertain the status from the area51 page, and there's no easy way to know that's where a (new) user should look for that information. Maybe an easy to find link to the area51 page would help?

Answer (score 4):

[yhw42's answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/789/countdown-indicator-to-end-of-beta-or-count-up-from-the-start/790#790) is correct, but as to the countdown, the launch date has not been established.  This is because each site launch takes a custom effort for the design, and there is currently a backlog.  At present, [programmers.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) is being worked on, and *hopefully* the work on RPG will start after that.